# How to pass named parameters to another script in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to pass all parameters from one powershell script to another script without knowing the named parameters. That other script is out of my control and I can not predict all the parameters it takes.

Example wrapper: `wrapper.ps1`

```
Set-StrictMode -v 2
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"

write-host "ArgsIn:" $Args

$mypath= Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$Cmd, $NewArgs =$Args | foreach { $_ -replace "one",'two' }
$Cmd = $mypath+"\"+$Cmd

write-host "Running:" $Cmd $NewArgs

& $Cmd @NewArgs
exit $LastExitCode
```

Example called script: `test.ps1`)

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string]$BAR,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string]$FOO
)

write-host "test: Args:" $Args
write-host "FOO" $FOO
write-host "BAR" $BAR

exit 0
```

If I call `test.ps1` it works as expected:

```
PS C:\Test> .\test.ps1 -foo one -bar three
test: Args:
FOO one
BAR three
```

But if I try it via the wrapper, it maps the parameters positionally instead.

```
PS C:\Test> .\wrapper.ps1 test.ps1 -foo one
ArgsIn: test.ps1 -foo one
Running: C:\Test\test.ps1 -foo two
test: Args: test.ps1 -foo one
FOO two
BAR -foo
```

I have tried various alternative forms to call the script (including `invoke-command` and `invoke-expression`).

One way that appeared to work was using

```
invoke-expression "& `"$Cmd`" $NewArgs"
```

but that breaks as soon as any parameter contains a space:

```
PS C:\Test> .\wrapper.ps1 test.ps1 -foo "one three"
ArgsIn: test.ps1 -foo one three
Running: C:\Test\test.ps1 -foo two three
test: Args:
FOO two
BAR three
```

Is there any sensible way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [About Splatting Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6#syntax):

> To provide parameter values for positional parameters, in which
>   parameter names are not required, use the **array** syntax. To provide
>   parameter name and value pairs, use the **hash table** syntax. The
>   splatted value can appear anywhere in the parameter list.

In other words, if want to pass **named** parameters, you should splat your parameters as a hash table (rather than a array). Something like:

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param (
    $Cmd,
    [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$RemainingArguments
)
Set-StrictMode -v 2
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"

$Cmd = $PSScriptRoot + '\' + $Cmd
$ArgName = $Null; $NewArgs = @{}
ForEach ($Arg in $RemainingArguments) {
    If ($Arg.StartsWith('-')) {$ArgName = $Arg.SubString(1)}
    ElseIf ($ArgName) {$NewArgs[$ArgName] = $Arg}
}

# $NewArgs['Foo'] = 'Three test'

write-host "Running:" $Cmd $NewArgs 

& $Cmd @NewArgs
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> .\wrapper.ps1 test.ps1 -foo 'one three'
Running: C:\...\test.ps1 System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
test: Args:
FOO one three
BAR
```

Comment: Convenient way to get args as hash ->

`@args` insteads of `$args`

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled on something that works:

```
 & powershell.exe -file $Cmd @NewArgs
```

But it feels ugly to call a second powershell instance to do what I need.

Maybe there is a cleaner version.