# PowerShell: How to forward unparsed parameters to functions?

Tags: function, powershell, function-parameter

I'm trying to pass unparsed arguments "through" to a function call, but am having trouble getting powershell to parse them. See below code:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)] 
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [Alias("m", "mixno", "mix")] [int]$script:mix = 2,               
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [Alias("c", "command")] [String]$script:command = "help",
      [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] [string[]]$script:otherargs)

function f1{
    param([switch]$s1)
    Write-host "Unbound Args: $($MyInvocation.UnboundArguments)"
    Write-Host "s1: $s1"
}

&"$script:command" @script:otherargs
```

Result:

```
.\argstest.ps1 -c f1 -s1

Unbound Args: -s1

s1: False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass named parameters to another script in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507154/how-to-pass-named-parameters-to-another-script-in-powershell)

Comment: So I have to build a hash table? Seems like there should be an easier way to do it.

Comment: if you want to pass **named** parameters: yes. In case you want to pass **positional** parameters (which is tricky as you might have bound parameters as well), you might simply build an array of the unbound parameters.